# My login to the iPhone Gmail app does not show up under 'apps connected to your account'

Tags: gmail, ios

I'm logged into my Gmail account on my iPhone via the Gmail app. For some reason, the iPhone does not show up in the 'apps connected to your account' section of the My Account page when I check my email on my Macbook (running OS X 10.11.2). However, the iPhone does show up in the 'recently used devices' section. I do know that before, the iPhone would show up in the apps connected section, but it's not now. Why?

It's on an iPhone with iOS 9.2.

Comment: That is odd. Caching perhaps? Or possibly because you're on the same wifi (and thus same WAN IP address) Google is treating them as the same connection?

Comment: @ Al E. - I removed the account and logged in again using my mobile data connection. Same result, still doesn't come up under the connected apps section.

Comment: Did you get an answer to this? I have an iPhone signed in and I check email frequently but the iPhone never shows up in the recently used devices.